# USB 3 XIMEA Camera xiQ: error while installing software package in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, camera, ximea

Hi I recently buy a XIMEA xiQ USB 3 Camera. It's working in windows properly but when I try to use this in ubuntu facing below error although i follow same instruction as recommend in [Website](https://www.ximea.com/support/wiki/apis/XIMEA_Linux_Software_Package)

See error:

> sipl@sipl-System-Product-Name:~$ /opt/XIMEA/bin/xiCamToolxiAPI: XIMEA Camera API V4.13.18.00
>   xiAPI: Adding camera context: dwID=11600851  ptr=880B4000 processID=00000BCA
>   xiAPI: Create handles 1 Process 00000BCA
>   xiAPI: Enable sensor
>   xiAPI: xiReadFileFFS 'SensFPNCorrections' not found
>   xiAPI: ScmCorrectorA::LoadAndParseConfigurationFile Warning: file SensFPNCorrections not found
>   xiAPI: xiReadFileFFS 'SensFPNCorrections' not found
>   xiAPI: ScmCorrectorA::LoadAndParseConfigurationFile Warning: file SensFPNCorrections not found
>   xiAPI: Frequency 114 71
>   xiAPI: Enabled 1 bandwidth 48000000
>   xiAPI: Time needed to read BPL:142ms
>   xiAPI: Successfully parsed BPL file, 1829 total corrected pixels
>   xiAPI: SetGPIO 1 set to 8
>   xiAPI: Frequency 50 31
>   xiAPI: Enabled 1 bandwidth 48000000
>   xiAPI: SetGPIO 1 set to 0
>   xiAPI: AutoSetBandwidth measurement
>   xiAPI: CalculateResources : Context 880B4000 ID 11600851 m_maxBytes=512 m_maxBufferSize=524288
>   xiAPI: Failed to change thread scheduler, check user limit for realtime priority.
>   xiAPI: AutoSetBandwidth measured 393Mbps. Safe margin 10% will be used.
>   xiAPI: Current bandwidth limit auto-set to 353 Mbps (min:80Mbps,max:393Mbps)
>   xiAPI: Frequency 50 31
>   xiAPI: Enabled 1 bandwidth 44125000
>   xiAPI: Frequency 46 2d
>   xiAPI: Enabled 1 bandwidth 44125000
>   xiAPI: ---- Device opened. Model:MQ013CG-E2 SN:11600851 FwF1: API:V4.13.18.00 ----
>   xiAPI: XIA(8150):xiGetParam (hdr) Finished with ERROR: 106
>   0x7ff69bebd940 ../../src/xiViewer/xiCore/xiApiWrapper.cpp L 338 :  "xiApi_GetParamInt(): xiGetParamInt(hdr) returned 106"
>   xiAPI: XIA(8150):xiGetParam (hdr_kneepoint1:min) Finished with ERROR: 106
>   0x7ff69bebd940 ../../src/xiViewer/xiCore/xiApiWrapper.cpp L 338 :  "xiApi_GetParamInt(): xiGetParamInt(hdr_kneepoint1:min) returned 106"
>   xiAPI: XIA(8150):xiGetParam (hdr_kneepoint1:max) Finished with ERROR: 106
>   0x7ff69bebd940 ../../src/xiViewer/xiCore/xiApiWrapper.cpp L 338 :  "xiApi_GetParamInt(): xiGetParamInt(hdr_kneepoint1:max) returned 106"

Answer (score 0):

Please create support ticket in the XIMEA public tracker:
https://www.ximea.com/support where our support personel
will help you to solve this issue. Also please include the
information about installed SW package version, camera model
and serial number. Thank you.

Best regards,
XIMEA Team

Comment: Hi, my colleague noticed your failed registration. Please try again.

Comment: @m.zajiko please see this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/922910/usb-3-ximea-camera-xiq-error-while-installing-software-package-in-ubuntu